# Regular expression not matching RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-4.0

I want this text to match:

```
test123
id=125456
```

This is my regular expression which is not working:

```
([iI]{1,1}[dD]{1,1}=((d+).))|([A-Za-z0-9]*)
```

Can anybody tell me what am I missing? The 2nd sample is not working.

Comment: Note that `([A-Za-z0-9]*)` will match an empty string.

Comment: fyi: There are many RegEx test sites available that make life a little easier for quick checks, e.g. [RegExLib](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) and [Derek Slager's](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) site.  I'd also recommend an extension to Visual Studio: [Regex Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55c24bf1-2636-4f94-831d-28db8505ce00) from some outfit named Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\d+` to match multiple digits.  `d+` looks for repeating character `d`:

```
...((\d+).))|(
     ^^ add \ in front of d
```

Working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/R8cxjZoG58

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick:
`([iI][dD]=\d+)|([A-Za-z0-9]*)`

Few pointers:

- `[iI]{1,1}` can be replaced with `[iI]{1}` and since once is the default you can omit the `{1}` completely.
- `d+` matches one or more times the letter 'd', `\d+` matches one or more digits.